# R tapply: different R releases produce different outputs

Tags: r, tapply

## The Problem

This a simple `tapply` example:

```
z=data.frame(s=as.character(NA), rows=c(1,2,1), cols=c(1,1,2), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
tapply(z$s, list(z$rows, z$cols), identity)
```

On R (Another Canoe) v3.3.3 (2017-03-06) for Windows, it brings:

```
#   1  2 
# 1 NA NA
# 2 NA NA
```

On R (You Stupid Darkness) v3.4.0 (2017-04-21) for Windows, it brings:

```
#   1  2 
# 1 NA NA
# 2 NA ""
```

## R News References

According to 
[NEWS.R-3.4.0.](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/NEWS.R-3.4.0.html):

> `tapply()` gets new option `default = NA` allowing to change the previously hardcoded value.

In this instance instead, it seems like if it defaults to an empty string.

## Inconsistencies Among Data Types

The new behavior is inconsistent with the numeric or logical version, where one still gets all NAs:

```
z=data.frame(s=as.numeric(NA), rows=c(1,2,1), cols=c(1,1,2), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
tapply(z$s, list(z$rows, z$cols), identity)

#    1  2
# 1 NA NA
# 2 NA NA
```

The same is for `s=NA`, which means `s=as.logical(NA)`.

## An Even Worse Case

In a more realistic context the character vector `s` in `z` has several values including NAs.

```
z=data.frame(s=c('a', NA, 'c'), rows=c(1,2,1), cols=c(1,1,2), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
m=tapply(z$s, list(z$rows, z$cols), identity)
z;m

#      s rows cols
# 1    a    1    1
# 2 <NA>    2    1
# 3    c    1    2

#   1   2  
# 1 "a" "c"
# 2 NA  ""
```

In general, we might fix this setting missing values for combinations with no values:

```
m[!nzchar(m)]=NA; m
#   1   2  
# 1 "a" "c"
# 2 NA  NA
```

Now when  there is no value, such as in `(2,2)`, one correctly gets a `NA`, like in the old versions.
But what if the input of `tapply` already has some empty strings?

```
z=data.frame(s=c('a', NA, ''), rows=c(1,2,1), cols=c(1,1,2), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
m=tapply(z$s, list(z$rows, z$cols), identity)
z;m

#      s rows cols
# 1    a    1    1
# 2 <NA>    2    1
# 3         1    2

#   1   2 
# 1 "a" ""
# 2 NA  ""
```

Now there is no way to distinguish between the *legal* empty string in `(1,2)` and that artificially added  in `(2,2)`  in place of the `NA` by the new tapply. So we can't apply the fix.

## Questions

Is really the new behavior the correct one?
That is, if there is no string  for `rows=2` and `cols=2`, why this  is not reported as a missing value (`NA`) and why this is so only for character data types?

Can we rewrite the code above in such a way to get a consistent behavior across R versions?

Comment: If you change it to `z <- data.frame(s = NA, ...` it would give NA

Comment: @beetroot: right you are. I updated the question

Comment: @akrun: `s=as.character(NA)` is just intended to help understanding where the problem is, i.e. in character NAs. In practice, it would be something like `s=c('a', NA, 'c')`.

Comment: It seems that the issue can be isolated to the fact that `array(character(), c(1, 1))` (something similar is used to initialize the returned value inside `tapply`) does not return `NA_character_` but `""` _in contrast_  to the "Value" section of `?array`.